# insert new term as tag on node submit

Tags: taxonomy-terms, forms

I want to add a term to the the node whenever it is submitted or edited. I have the term id of the term I want to add. 
My first approach of putting this code inside the custom node submit function is not working.

```
function module_custom_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
   $nid = $form_state['nid'];
   $node = node_load($nid);
   $term_id = '73';
   $node->taxonomy[] = $term_id;
   node_save($node);
}
```

This does not insert the taxonomy term with ID equal to 73.

My second approach was to put query inside the submit function. Though this made changes to the database, the taxonomy terms were not added as tags on the website for the corresponding node.

```
function module_custom_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
  $query = db_select('node', 'n');
  $query->fields('n', array('created', 'sticky'))
   ->condition('nid', $nid, '=');

   $result = $query->execute();
   foreach ($result as $record) {
     $time = $record->created;
     $sticky = $record->sticky;
   }

   db_insert('taxonomy_index')
   ->fields(array('nid' => $nid, 'tid' => $term_id, 'sticky' => $sticky, 'created' => $time))
   ->execute();
}
```

Are there any corrections, or alternative ways?

This approach seems to be working for now. I just added this to the submission handler.

```
   $node = node_load($nid);
   $term_id = '73';
   $node->field_tags[$node->language][]['tid'] = $term_id;
   node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using code from Drupal 6 in your first example, but from your second you must be using Drupal 7...`$node->taxonomy` isn't used in Drupal 7, taxonomy terms are related to entities via fields instead.

Your second example isn't working because the `taxonomy_index` table is just an index table relating nodes to terms...the hard-link between those two entities is actually contained in the field reference, which you haven't updated.

If I could offer a different approach, it would be to use [`hook_node_presave()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7). Using that method you can simply add another term id to the list of selected terms from the form, and rely on the node/field API to commit the changes and update the cache on your behalf.

```
function MYMODULE_node_presave($node) {
  $term_id = 73;

  // In reality you'd want to loop through the existing field values and check to 
  // avoid duplicates; this is just an example to actually set the value.
  if ($node->type == 'mytype') {
    $node->field_term_reference_field_name[$node->language][] = array('tid' => $term_id);
  }
}
```

As an added benefit this will also work for any nodes that you add programatically, not just those added/edited through the node form.

Comment: i added the code to my module and set the node type as 'article' just to test it but it's not working for me. 
PS - I've edited my question to include another way that worked for me. any views on it ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it at all, no, except that you're incurring 2 potentially database-heavy function calls by loading and saving the node, whereas using it in the presave hook you don't get any of that overhead (not sure why it's not working). If that's not a concern then I think you're OK, there's no reason why that code would break anything

Comment: woops its working now ! just a typo error. Meanwhile 2 more questions to trouble you with- 1. Is my 3rd approach better or using this hook ? 
2. By default the field name for tags field assigned for article node is "field_tags" , how can I derive this programmatically and if at all it is associated with a node or not ?

Comment: ok so question 1 you've answered thanks.. 
about 2) more- the reason I'm asking this is cause I only want to tag the node if field_tags is enabled.

Comment: Getting the name of the field is a bit of a pain as you'd have to load the taxonomy vocabulary (for the vid) and traverse all fields attached to the node type to see if any of them match. You can find out if the field exists on the node type with a single call though: `if (field_info_instance('node', 'field_tags', 'type_name')) { ...`

Comment: hmm ok.. final question - on nodes for which there is no field for tags, but still i want to tag the node by letting the user choose from a couple of options, is there a way to do this ? I mean all I want is the association of the particular node with the term.

Comment: No there's no built in way to do that, associating a node to a taxonomy term is done using a field

Answer (score 0):

You first need to add a taxonomy term reference field to your content type (i.e. field_page_terms) and then add the term like this:

```
$node = $form_state['node'];
$node->field_page_terms[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['tid'] = 73;
node_save($node);
```